# React native animation not working if used before/after useState

Tags: react-native, animation

I have a react native animation function which rotates a Animated View component. The animation is working normally if its called directly. But if its called with a setState function it is not working properly. Here is my functional component code.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const rotateData = rotateValueHolder.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1], outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
});

const startAnimation = () => {
    rotateValueHolder.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(rotateValueHolder, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 3000,
        easing: Easing.linear,
        useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start(() => startAnimation());
};


const loadData = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    startAnimation()
    try {
        let res = await axios.get(API_URL);
        let data = res.data;
        setLoading(false)
    } catch(err){
        // some code
        setLoading(false)
    }
}

return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={loadData}>
        <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ rotate: rotateData }] }}>
            <RotatingIcon />
        </Animated.View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
)
```

But if I removed the setLoading functions inside loadData(), the animation is working.

I added a console.log() inside the startAnimation(). It was called even though the animation is not working.

Comment: What `loading` state is doing on view? It looks l‪ike loading state might conflicting on view so animation couldn't work. Please share more code

Comment: I added all the component code